# How to handle Asynchronous images and video when adding image as SubView?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, asynchronous

I have a collection view where I add either an image or a video depending on the kind of media in a `Media()` object.

What I am unsure about is how I could use something like SDWebbImage when adding the video or image as a SubView instead of adding it to a UIImage view.

```
        if postArray[indexPath.item].media[0].imageURLString != nil { //its an image
        print("display image")

        var imageView = UIImageView(image: postArray[indexPath.item].media[0].imageURLString!)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 126, height: 203)//cell.frame
        cell.imageOrVideoView//Here I need to add image
            //.addSubview(imageView)//Here I would usualy add a UIImage to subview
```

I have also asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821738/does-storing-a-uiimage-come-with-the-asynchronous-problems-using-a-url-does) regarding the same general topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** you shouldn't add subviews inside `cellForItemAt` as the cell is dequeud and this will overflow the content and mix them unless you clear it before reuse , but you need to create an outlet or imageView once as an instance var then use it

**Second:** it's better to have a separete cell for image and another for video

**Finally:** use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) for images and [VGPlayer](https://github.com/VeinGuo/VGPlayer) for videos

Comment: So I should: 1) create 2 customCells one for image with imageView and one for video with (imageView?), 2) use SDWEBImage (done) and VGPlayer (Is this like sdwebimage for video?) Does video have the same problems as image when it comes to being asynchronous?

Comment: for the video , they provide a sample for the table here https://github.com/VeinGuo/VGPlayer/tree/master/VGPlayerExample/VGPlayerExample/Embed download the example and follow it , regarding the playing you need to only set a thumbnail to the video and play it upon click , the library will cash played videos , in your video model if you don't have image thumbnail url you can generate one from the remote video